# TypeError: takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python, rss

I am using python to generate a rss file,but when i call this method, it post a error"`TypeError: writeRssFile() takes exactly 0 arguments (1 given)`"

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# encoding: utf-8
import os,PyRSS2Gen
def writeRssFile(*newslist):
   item =[]
   for i in range(0,len(newslist)):
        item.append(PyRSS2Gen.RSSItem(
            title = newslist[i].get('title'),
            description = newslist[i].get('content'),
            pubDate = datetime.datetime.now()))
   rss = PyRSS2Gen.RSS2(
   title = "Andrew's PyRSS2Gen feed",
   link = "http://www.dalkescientific.com/Python/PyRSS2Gen.html",
   description = "The latest news about PyRSS2Gen, a "
                 "Python library for generating RSS2 feeds",
   lastBuildDate = datetime.datetime.now(),
   items = item[:],
   )

   rss.write_xml(open("pyrss2gen.xml", "w"))
```

i want call this method like this way:

```
newslist=[{'title':'title1','content':'content1'},{'title':'title2','content':'content2'}]
writeRssFile(newslist)
```

I had try googling on this but I'm not really very sure what is the exactly reason, so hopefully can get help from here.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You accept variable number of arguments. So, you need to unpack the list while calling, like this

```
writeRssFile(*newslist)
```

Also, you need to import `datetime` module.

Apart from that, when the `range` actually starts from `0`, you can omit that. So,

```
range(0, len(newslist))
```

is the same as

```
range(len(newslist))
```

Comment: The OP's code shouldn't produce that error, though, it's effectively identical to `def foo(*args): pass; foo([1,2,3])` which works fine. I'm not convinced the code above is the same as what was erroring.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor You are correct, it was actually failing not being able to do `.get` on a list. But, if we unpack it, the problem can be resolved.

Comment: Ah, the joys of providing solutions when given the wrong information.. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer,I  tried in that way,but it doesn't work,and post a same error "TypeError: writeRssFile() takes exactly 0 arguments (2 given)"

Comment: @Elivis Is it part of a class?

Comment: No,that is just a method

Comment: @Elivis Actually it creates the XML file for me, with the same code